# Undefined method `haml' when rendering haml in Pony mail from scheduled job

Tags: sinatra, haml, rufus-scheduler, pony

I have a sinatra app that executes cucumber tests and sends email notification with their results. Email gem is Pony, and there is a haml template for this notification.

This logic works within a route:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'pony'

get "/execute_all/?" do
  execute_all_tests()
  Pony.mail :to => "recipients@email.com",
      :from => "do-not-reply@email.com",
      :subject => "Test results,
      :html_body => haml(:email_layout)

      redirect "/"

end
```

However when I use scheduled job with rufus scheduler for these actions, I get following exception:

```
scheduler caught exception:
undefined method `haml' for main:Object
```

Code is copypasta from route:

```
   scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
   scheduler.every '2h' do
      execute_all_tests()
      Pony.mail :to => "recipients@email.com",
          :from => "do-not-reply@email.com",
          :subject => "Test results,
          :html_body => haml(:email_layout)
   end
```

All two methods are in the same file, that is executed to run Sinatra app.

How to get rid of this exception, and send emails with haml template as scheduled job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `haml` method is only available in the context of a request to Sinatra (it is an instance method on `Sinatra::Base`), and it can’t be used outside of a Sinatra request.

In order to render a Haml template, you can use the Haml API directly:

```ruby
haml_template = File.read(File.join(settings.views, 'email_layout.haml'))

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
  scheduler.every '2h' do
    execute_all_tests()
    Pony.mail :to => "recipients@email.com",
      :from => "do-not-reply@email.com",
      :subject => "Test results",
      :html_body => Haml::Engine.new(haml_template).render(binding)
  end
end
```

Here I’m assuming `execute_all_tests` is using instance variables that are referenced in the Haml template, so we pass the `binding` to the Haml `render` method to access these variables. You might also need to pass in any Haml options you need as the second parameter to `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running rufus and sinatra as the same user?  That seems to be the recurrent theme in a lot of these problems.